Vulnerability Risk: Sequential numbering pattern of Address ID
How can I prevent an attacker from exploiting the sequential numbering pattern of address IDs in my application, which allows them to delete addresses belonging to other users and potentially lead to a mass deletion of addresses affecting a large number/all application users?

Magento sends form_key (Magento's implementation of Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) token) while submitting data and verify it at server end to make sure the request has been made from legit webpage.
Now, you can argue that a person can change the form data using js or some other method and make it so that it inject some other address id other than the customer's own address id, but the default controller \Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\Delete which handles delete operation already takes care of it at server side as it validates if the deletion request is made by owner of the address using following piece of code
\Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\Delete @line 28
if ($address->getCustomerId() === $this->_getSession()->getCustomerId()) {

If you want to implement custom delete operation somewhere, I would recommend you apply the same checks.
